# Django python help needed

Tags: python, django, django-south, manage.py

I am trying to sync my DB but at time of sync it shows error to migrate my models.py containing folder on migrating it shows no fixtures found.

I have pasted the messages which it shows:

```
C:\election\trunk\election-server\geodjango>manage.py syncdb

Syncing...
No fixtures found.

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.admin
 > django.contrib.gis
 > south
 > django_extensions

Not synced (use migrations):
 - india
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
```

And on migrating, it shows this message:

```
C:\election\trunk\election-server\geodjango>manage.py migrate
Running migrations for india:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for india.
No fixtures found.
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first paragraph is a little confusing to me.  If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like something I ran into.

Initial data for a database is stored in the file `initial_data.json` by default.  The migration messages you are getting indicate that you're using the django migration tool South.  IF you do not have any initial data, you can tell South to ignore initial data with this command:

```
./manage.py migrate --no-initial-data
```

Does that help?

Comment: now when i migrate my app say "india" it shows that         django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "india_problemreported" already exists how can i get rid of this error now.

Comment: That may be because when you ran the migration intially, without `--no-initial-data`, it created the database but only partially migrated it.  That's just a hunch, though.  You can try removing your database (back it up if you need to!), and run ./manage.py migrate india --no-initial-data.  Check http://south.aeracode.org/docs/commands.html for the full list of South commands and instructions.

Comment: Since it works, would you mind selecting the answer as correct?  Thanks. :)